# drop_caches file not found not allowing me to create one either (with root access)

Tags: linux, caching

Could someone help please?

I ran the following command:
sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

It gave me the following error message:
bash: /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches: No such file or directory

I searched the forum but I could not find why its giving this error message. I running this as root.

Here is the output of my uname -a command:
Linux ceast221s10 2.6.9-55.ELsmp #1 SMP Fri Apr 20 17:03:35 EDT 2007 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Comment: Are you running RHEL 4? http://nixcraft.com/showthread.php/15578-Can-we-free-up-cached-RAM suggests that /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches was not in RHEL 3, so maybe it is not in your old version either.

Comment: We are running rhel 4 (update 5)

Comment: `2.6.9-55.ELsmp` is an *extremely* old kernel. Probably before the `drop_caches` functionality existed... `2.6.12` was released in June of 2005 - `2.6.9` was obviously sometime before that...

Comment: Just for the record, it appears `drop_caches` was first released in kernel `2.6.16` (technically the release candidates leading up to it, but that's the first "official" release containing it).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches is not present in old versions of RHEL.

You indicated in the comments that you are using RHEL 4 update 5.

As you can see at https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5409 entitled "What is the purpose of /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches in Red Hat Enterprise Linux?", /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches was added from RHEL update 6:

> Environment
>
> ```
> Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) version 4 Update 6 or later
> Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 5
> Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 6
> ```

So to use this approach you will need to update to a newer version.

That is probably worth doing sooner rather than later, as https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/errata/ shows the support lifecycle for RHEL, and end of extended life phase for RHEL 4 is February 28, 2015. In addition, the Extended Update Sipport (EUS) section notes:

> In Red Hat Enterprise Linux 4, EUS was available for the following
>   minor releases:
>
> ```
> 4.5 (ends January 31, 2009)
> 4.7 (ends August 31st, 2011)
> ```